# Is there an efficient algorithm that allows to construct a binary word with particular properties related to its horizontal and vertical “subwords”?

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, combinatorics-on-words

Let $w$ denote an $mn$-bit word (i.e. a binary word of length $mn$). Assuming that $b_{i,j}$ denote individual bits, we can represent $w$ in the “rectangular” form as follows:

$$\begin{array}{l}
b_{1.1}b_{1.2} \ldots b_{1.(m-1)}b_{1.m}\\
b_{2.1}b_{2.2} \ldots b_{2.(m-1)}b_{2.m}\\
\ldots\\
b_{(n-1).1}b_{(n-1).2} \ldots b_{(n-1).(m-1)}b_{(n-1).m}\\
b_{n.1}b_{n.2} \ldots b_{n.(m-1)}b_{n.m}.
\end{array}$$

Then $$H_{i,m}(w) = b_{i.1}b_{i.2} \ldots b_{i.(m-1)}b_{i.m}$$ are $m$-bit *horizontal subwords* of $w$ (for $1 \leq i \leq n$) and $$V_{n,i}(w) = b_{1.i}b_{2.i} \ldots b_{(n-1).i}b_{n.i}.$$ are $n$-bit *vertical subwords* of $w$ (for $1 \leq i \leq m$).

Given a pair of *arbitrary* (see note 1 below) integers $(m, n),$ I am interested in an efficient algorithm that allows to construct an example of an $mn$-bit word $W$ that satisfies all of the following five properties:

1. All $m$-bit horizontal subwords of $W$ are different from each other;
2. All $n$-bit vertical subwords of $W$ are different from each other;
3. Any $m$-bit horizontal subword of $W$ is different from any $n$-bit vertical subword of $W$, i.e. there does not exist an $m$-bit horizontal subword of $W$ that is equal to some $n$-bit vertical subword of $W$ (this property is automatically satisfied if $m \neq n$);
4. The number of non-zero bits in any $m$-bit horizontal subword of $W$ is equal to $m/2$;
5. The number of non-zero bits in any $n$-bit vertical subword of $W$ is equal to $n/2$.

Is it possible to solve this problem?

**Note 1.**
Obviously, both $m$ and $n$ must be even and such that $m \leq \binom{n}{n/2}, n \leq \binom{m}{m/2}.$ Maybe there are some other requirements for $(m, n).$ For example, if $m=8, n=8,$ does there exist a $64$-bit word $W_{64}$ satisfying the above conditions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design

Comment: You won't prove the non-existence of $W_{64}$. Constructed by hand: `1111000001011100001100111100100100001111001101011100011010101010`

Comment: @PeterTaylor: thank you. I wonder whether it is possible to estimate the number of such words in the set of all $k$-bit words...

Comment: @PeterTaylor: yes, if $m=8, n=8$, we have $\binom{8}{4}=70$ (the number of possible options for a horizontal/vertical $8$-bit subword), which is _significantly_ greater than $m + n = 16$ (the number of all subwords, horizontal and vertical), so it would be reasonable to assume that $W_{64}$ exists.

Answer (score 2):

This construction works for $n=m$ both powers of 2.
Take an enumeration of the truth tables of the linear functions
$$\{[\langle a,x\rangle: x \in GF(2)^k],a \in GF(2)^k\}.$$
This will have the weight property *except* for the fact that the first row and column will be all zeroes, for example, for $k=3,$ we get

[image].

Call this matrix $A,$ and let $J$ be the all one matrix with the same dimensions. The blockmatrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
A+J & A \\
A & A+J 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
*almost* has the desired property with size $n=m=2^{k+1}.$ In this case we get

[image]

I have taken an $8\times 8$ seed matrix but one can take smaller ones or larger ones as needed.

The problem is the rows and columns match. To remove this, I have rotated the rows of the matrix to the right by one. Note that the original rows of matrix $A$ were the linear multivariate boolean functions, and shifting them by one yields nonlinear functions, so they are now distinct from the columns. The final outcome is below:

[image]

I used the magma calculator online available [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/). The code is below (without the cyclic rotation):

V:=VectorSpace(GF(2),3);
L:=[v: v in V];

A:=Matrix([[InnerProduct(L[i+1],L[j]): j in [1..8]]: i in [0..7]]);A;

J:=Matrix([[1: i in [1..8]]: j in [1..8]]);
C:=BlockMatrix(2,2,[A+J,A,A,A+J]); C;

function GetRowW(A,j,n) return Weight(VectorSpace(GF(2),n)![A[j,k]: k in [1..n]]); end function;

function GetColW(A,j,n) return Weight(VectorSpace(GF(2),n)![A[k,j]: k in [1..n]]); end function;

"row weights",{* GetRowW(C,j,16): j in [1..16] *};

"number of rows"; #{ [C[j,k]: k in [1..16]]: j in [1..16] };

"column weights",{* GetColW(C,j,16): j in [1..16] *};

"number of cols"; #{ [C[j,k]: j in [1..16]]: k in [1..16] };

Comment: In the given $16 \times 16$ matrix the $i$-th row (horizontal subword) is equal to the $i$-th column (vertical subword), which contradicts Property #3.

Comment: see my edit please